# Use binary operators to change the bits of a number

Tags: java

I am solving an exercise which I think I am not far from the solution, so I need some clarification please, here is the exercise below:

The **VenueOptions** class is designed to store the characteristics of **bars** by changing the bits of a single digit stored in the `status` property.
The characteristics that can be activated or deactivated are stored in an enumeration which contains the representations in the form of integer numbers of the corresponding bits: `VenueOption.option`.
The enumeration contains:

- *VenueOptions.option.FOOD (1)*
- *VenueOptions.option.ALCOHOL (2)*
- *VenueOptions.option.MUSIC (4)*

By activating or deactivating these bits in the `status` property, we can represent and test all the combinations of characteristics of a **bar**. When we talk about activating a bit, it means that we set this bit to **1** and when we talk to deactivate a bit, this means that we set this bit to **0**.

You can get the value of `status` with the `statusInt ()` method and change it with the `setSatusInt ()` method.

Create the **VenueOptionsImpl** class.It descends from the **VenueOptions** class, you must write the code for the following methods:

- `setOption (option opt)`. For a given opt, it sets the corresponding
  bit in the status property.
- `unsetOption (option opt)`. For a    given opt, it turns off the
  corresponding bit in the `status` property.
- `optionIsSet (option opt)`. Returns **true** if the bit corresponding
  to opt is set, otherwise returns
  **false**.
- `supports (VenueOption check)`.Returns **true** if the bit or bits enabled in the `status` property of the **VenueOptions** object, passed as a parameter, are also enabled in the current object, otherwise returns **false**.
  The values of the other bits of the current object are not taken into account, so if in `check`, only the value **FOOD** is activated, and in the current object, the values **FOOD** and **MUSIC** are activated then the method must return **true** .
- `toString ()`.Returns a string that represents the binary value of the status property, such as **111** or **11** or **100**.
  Here is the code to complete below:

```
public class ExerciceImpl4 {
    public void runExercise( String[] argv ) throws Exception {
        VenueOptionsImpl db = new VenueOptionsImpl();

        db.setOption( VenueOptions.option.FOOD );
        db.setOption( VenueOptions.option.ALCOHOL );

        System.out.println("<pre>");
        System.out.println(""+db);

        if ( db.optionIsSet( VenueOptions.option.ALCOHOL ) ) {
            System.out.println("ALCOHOL est activé");
        }

        if ( db.optionIsSet( VenueOptions.option.FOOD  ) ) {
            System.out.println("FOOD est activé");
        }

        VenueOptionsImpl support = new VenueOptionsImpl();
        support.setOption( VenueOptions.option.FOOD );
        support.setOption( VenueOptions.option.ALCOHOL );

        if ( db.supports( support ) ) {
            System.out.println("Propose FOOD and ALCOHOL");
        }

        support.setOption( VenueOptions.option.MUSIC );
        if ( ! db.supports( support ) ) {
            System.out.println("ne propose PAS MUSIC");
        }
        System.out.println("</pre>");
    }
}

abstract class VenueOptions {
    private int status = 0;

    public enum option {
        FOOD ( 1 ),
        ALCOHOL ( 2 ),
        MUSIC ( 4 );
        public final int num;
        option( int num ) {
            this.num = num;
        }
    }

    public int statusInt() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatusInt( int num ) {
        this.status = num;
    }

    abstract public void setOption( option opt );
    abstract public void unsetOption( option opt );
    abstract public boolean optionIsSet( option opt );
    abstract public boolean supports( VenueOptions check );
    abstract public String toString();
}

class VenueOptionsImpl extends VenueOptions {
    
 / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE ABOVE THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET ON RUN ---------- * /

     / **** Enter your code here **** /

     / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- * /
  
}
```

Voici le code que je propose:

```
class VenueOptionsImpl extends VenueOptions {
    @Override
     public void setOption (option opt) {
         setStatusInt (1); // I activate the corresponding bit in the status property by the
                          // changing to 1.
     }

     @Override
     public void unsetOption (option opt) {
         setStatusInt (0); // I disable the corresponding bit in the status property by the
                         // changing to 0.
     }

     @Override
     public boolean optionIsSet (option opt) {
         if (setStatusInt (1)) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     }

     @Override
     public boolean supports (VenueOptions check) {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString () {
         return "VenueOptionsImpl {}";
     }
}
```

The `optionIsSet (option opt)` and `supports (VenueOptions check)` and `toString ()` methods are a bit complex for me and I'm not sure if the codes I implemented in these methods are correct? I'm having doubts,  can you give me a hand please?

Comment: Show how you would set a bit to 1, to 0, test a bit. And then bring the statusInt and option.num together.

Comment: When in doubt, write unit tests

Comment: i set the bit to 1 or to 0 by using the setStatusInt(int num) method but i don't know how to bring statusInt and option num together,do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you thought about using a BitSet? Do you have so much data that using bit-level operators is necessary?

Comment: yes i know bitset but i think i don't need it because the statement allows me to use setStatusInt(int num) et statusInt()